# Using IntelliJ debugger, is it possible to continue through a collection iteration until a variable returns null?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

The following code snippet is part of a Spring MVC controller.  Using commons-collections, it iterates over a List of County objects and transforms it into a List of String[] to return to the client.  Using the value from the "searchTerm" variable to find the data.  The problem I'm having is every so often, a particular search term causes the transformer to throw an exception because the County .getState() method seems to return null.  So I'm wondering if using IntelliJ's debugger, can I tell it to continually iterate until a variable is null.  A breakpoint causes me to step over each iteration manually, but with a large collection, that could take a while.

Thanks.

```
public List<String[]> cityLookup(@PathVariable String searchTerm) {
    List<County> counties = countyService.findAllByPartialCity(searchTerm);

    return new ArrayList<String[]>(CollectionUtils.collect(counties, new Transformer() {
        @Override
        public Object transform(Object o) {
            return new String[]{((County) o).getId().getCity(), ((County) o).getState().getStateCode()};
        }
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the breakpoints dialog there should be a conditions option.

http://jetbrains.dzone.com/tips/set-conditional-breakpoints-id

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do what you're suggesting.

I would recommend that you break that return line into two: one to fetch the values and another to construct the array to be returned.

You can put the breakpoint at the return line and inspect the values before you construct it.

Comment: What you suggest would still require me to step on each iteration.  Kevin's answer above for conditional breakpoints did the trick.